# Crystal report Issue after deployed ASP.NET MVC application to server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2017

I am facing an issue with Crystal Reporting. I developed an ASP.NET MVC application and use Crystal Reporting which is correct working at localhost and download report is also correct. But when I deployed to the server the report is not downloading and an error message is shown. Please help me to solve this issue.

Note: I searched on the web and found that install Crystal Report on running machine but the question that I deployed to the server and there how can I install Crystal Report.

Comment: **Remember**: we cannot read neither your screen, nor your mind. If you get an error - **you HAVE TO SHOW US** that error (full, complete, exact) error here - how else can we even begin to help you???

Comment: Please visit this link and then click on "Report" https://testwebsite1122.azurewebsites.net/

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurred because I Didn't give the permission to the folder of the report on the server. moreover, It can also happen when you publish your ASP NET MVC Application the folder does not contain the Report folder.